# How to save the pretrained model into pickel file

Tags: computer-vision, pickle, pre-trained-model

How can I save the pre-trained model into a pickle file?

I am working on the rembg model for background removal, But I don't know how to save the model into a pickle file. I need to deploy this model. please anyone help me, How to save this model into a pickle file.
This is the  model:
https://github.com/danielgatis/rembg

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
import pickle

pickle.dump(your_model, open('model.pkl', 'wb'))

pickled_model = pickle.load(open('model.pkl', 'rb'))

print(pickled_model.predict(X))
```